# Java media player not working in ubuntu11.04 ?

Tags: java, linux, mp3, ubuntu-11.04, jmf

I faced a problem when i tried to open media in  **linux**, despite that it was run perfectly  in the windows **!!!!!!**

*of course i have installed  the sun Java Media Framework and mp3plugin.jar !!!!*

### *The problem is :* when i open a File i get the following error:-

**When opening MP3 file :**

Unable to handle format: mpeglayer3, 44100.0 Hz, 16-bit, Stereo, LittleEndian, Signed, 16000.0 frame rate, FrameSize=32768 bits
Failed to realize: com.sun.media.PlaybackEngine@1401d28
Error: Unable to realize com.sun.media.PlaybackEngine@1401d28

---

**When opening .mpg**

Unable to handle format: MPEG, 352x240, FrameRate=29.9, Length=126720
Unable to handle format: mpeg audio, 44100.0 Hz, 16-bit, Stereo, LittleEndian, Signed, 28000.0 frame rate, FrameSize=32768 bits

---

The code was provided in the tutorial :-

http://www.deitel.com/articles/java_tutorials/20060422/PlayingVideowithJMF/

### [http://www.deitel.com/articles/java_tutorials/20060422/PlayingVideowithJMF/JMF_Page2.html](http://www.deitel.com/articles/java_tutorials/20060422/PlayingVideowithJMF/)

Please i really need your help ,because i tried to run many other programs but i got the same error ....

So please, i would be grateful for your help ....

Reem

Comment: You have the native code libraries available?

Comment: I installed the JMF libraries and the program works in windows,but in ubuntu it doesn't !!!!!!

Comment: Jars are not enough - you need native library support too.

Comment: Sorry,i'm confusing .. Could you tell me what do you mean by native library exactly, and from where can i get them !!! Excuse me for not understanding because i'm new in using both of java and linux .

Comment: Please, i really need help ...

Comment: Have a look at http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/jmfdiagnostics-139189.html

Answer (score 0):

you just need to install JMF in your system